# Improvements on Way to Append Copied Names with (1)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am working on an auction website in asp.net mvc. I have a method in my ItemsController that copies an item object as a new listing. My current code is listed below:

```
public ActionResult Copy(Guid id)
{
    Item item = db.Items.Find(id);
    Cat cat = db.Cats.Find(item.CatId);
    Item copy = new Item(Guid.NewGuid(), item.ItemName + " copy", 
      item.ItemDesc, item.ModelNo, item.RetailValue, item.ImageFileName,
      item.StartDate, item.EndDate, item.InitialBid, item.IncrementBy,
      null, null, null, cat);

    db.Items.Add(copy);
    db.SaveChanges();
    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Items", new {catId = item.CatId});
}
```

Right now, I am appending " copy" to every single copy. Instead what I would like to do is for example: "Item" then the first copy would be "Item (1)" and if they were to copy "Item" again the name would be "Item (2)" etc.

**Edit:**
I now have a new (updated for bugs in below comments)functioning method posted in my below answer.

> If anyone sees code improvements or a more efficient way to accomplish the same thing, let me know.

Comment: That seems the only way to go to me. Or adding something totally random, like "Chair-pT7r4WQmb8"

Comment: Yeah, it definitely has to still look clean so I will have to give my idea a try. Thank you

Comment: What happens when one of the items is removed? You could end out with "Item", "Item (1)" and "Item (3)". Do you really want to store this copy information in the database, or can you instead calculate it when you want to display it?

Comment: @stuartd I have to store it in the database like that unfortunately because the value of the name is a foreign key in my table and must be unique.

Comment: I have edited my post to contain my working code. I could cut the number variables down and condense lines, however I have it separated now for the sake of testing.

Comment: `db.Items.Where(i => i.ItemName.Contains(item.ItemName))` - wouldn't then "Grandfather Clock" match "Clock"?

Comment: A code improvement would be first to determine the new name and then set it, rather than have two calls to create the new item that only differ by the name.

Comment: Can any of your item names have brackets in? Like "Garden Chair (Wooden)?"

Comment: You are right in your clock example. I don't believe that will matter in at least in my use, but that is something to consider. And yep, that is definitely an improvement. I will update this now. Also something to consider is the parenthetical names, which actually does occur in my list of items that I did not consider. I will have to update my code from splitting from the parentheses .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public ActionResult Copy(Guid id)
    {
        Item item = db.Items.Find(id);
        Cat cat = db.Cats.Find(item.CatId);
        int newCopyValue = 0;
        string newName;

        List<Item> items = db.Items.Where(i => i.ItemName.Contains(item.ItemName)).OrderBy(i => i.ItemName.Length).ThenBy(i => i.ItemName).ToList();
        if (items.Count == 1)
        {
            newName = item.ItemName + " (1)";
        }
        else
        {
            Item lastCopy = items.ElementAt(items.Count - 1);
            String copyName = lastCopy.ItemName;

            if (copyName[copyName.Length - 3] == '(' && copyName[copyName.Length - 1] == ')')
            {
                newCopyValue = Convert.ToInt32(copyName[copyName.Length - 2].ToString()) + 1;
            }
            else if (copyName[copyName.Length - 4] == '(' && copyName[copyName.Length - 1] == ')')
            {
                string doubleDig = copyName[copyName.Length - 3].ToString() + copyName[copyName.Length - 2].ToString();
                newCopyValue = Convert.ToInt32(doubleDig) + 1;
            }
            newName = item.ItemName + " (" +  newCopyValue.ToString() + ")";
        }

        Item copy = new Item(Guid.NewGuid(), newName, item.ItemDesc, item.ModelNo, item.RetailValue, item.ImageFileName, item.StartDate, item.EndDate, item.InitialBid, item.IncrementBy, null, null, null, cat);

        db.Items.Add(copy);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Items", new {catId = item.CatId});
    }
```

New functioning method with double digit and support for parentheses in names. Could still run into issue with "Wood Clock" and "Clock" example.